# HP Deskjet 3050A scanner not working in Debian

Tags: debian, scanner

I have an HP Deskjet All-in-one 3050A.

In Debian Testing I installed it through CUPS and the printer works fine. However I can't say the same about the scanner. I've tried install it using HPLIP, but it's the same.

SANE or Simple Scan detect the scanner but at the time of use it, both say that there was a problem with I/O.

The weird part is that I've tried the scanner in two virtual machines (W7 and Linux Mint 14) hosted in the Debian Testing, and works fine in both VM's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting it as a network printer and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some problem with rights. You should check if your device in `/dev/bus/usb/*bus*/*device*` is correctly accessible to your user or the `scanner` group used by SANE.

In my configuration, with another multifunction printer, I get this:

```
$ lsusb | grep 03f0
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 03f0:5711 Hewlett-Packard PhotoSmart C4100 series
$ ls -l /dev/bus/usb/001/005
crw-rw-r-T+ 1 root lp 189, 4 gen 10 12:13 /dev/bus/usb/001/005
$ getfacl /dev/bus/usb/001/005
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/bus/usb/001/005
# owner: root
# group: lp
# flags: --t
user::rw-
user:giuseppe:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

In order to change group ownership or add user acl, you may create a file in `/lib/udev/rules.d` with your setting.

Comment: I have exactly the same configuration like you, except that my device is in 001/003 instead of 001/005. But owner and privileges are the same. Also I tried scan as root and the same. For example output of scanimage: scanimage: open of device hpaio:/usb/Deskjet_3050A_J611_series?serial=CN18B4D1JB05PJ failed: Error during device I/O

Comment: Of course bus/device numbers change every time you plug in the device. Could you execute your scanimage with strace: `strace -o /tmp/logfile -f -s64 scanimage ...`

Comment: What should I be looking for within the file? Because they are 20753 lines.

Comment: Anything about errors just before the error message is printed.